# React setState method not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am fairly new to react, and having learnt the basic concepts of state and props (which are similar to Vue which I am familiar with), I tried this little function.

```
expand = () => {
    this.setState((state, props) => ({
        height: state.height*2
    }), () => {
        console.log(this.state.height);
    });
}
```

The function is called from an onClick method in the rendered HTML.

The problem I have is that when I run the code, the `console.log()` prints the original height, and nothing changes on the actual page.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './draw.css';

class Task extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        width: 200,
        height: 35
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <foreignObject x={this.state.x} y={this.state.y}
            width={this.state.width} height={this.state.height}>
            <div className="task" style={{width: (this.state.width-22)+"px", 
            height: (this.state.height-22)+"px"}}
            onClick={this.expand}>
                Hello {this.props.name}
            </div>
        </foreignObject>
    );
}

expand = () => {
    this.setState((state, props) => ({
        height: state.height*2
    }), () => {
        console.log(this.state.height);
    });
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return {
        x: props.x,
        y: props.y,
        width: props.width,
        height: props.height
    }
}
}
export default Task;
```

The input given by the props is the same as that of the initial state.

Output from the console: `35`

Comment: @Abhilash OP is using the callback though, so nope.

Comment: @Abhilash that isn't the problem here. OP is using the callback of setState https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Why are you using `getDerivedStateFromProps`? Edit: you're passing props into `<Task />` I assume?

Comment: I'm thinking that when you set the state in `expand`, a rerender happens which causes `getDerivedStateFromProps` to execute. And those props are being put into the state. Are you passing `height: 35` as a prop to `Task`?

Comment: @bakar_dev OP is using the `state` parameter of the callback, this is fine. The problem is `getDerivedStateFromProps`, which runs before every render, not once as OP expects (I guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with this you are using `getDerivedStateFromProps`. If you go through react documentation it says:

> **getDerivedStateFromProps** is invoked right **before calling the render method**, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing

So what happens irrespective of you update any **setState** you are updating state value as you are expecting it from **props**. So everytime it will get value from props one not your state one. You dont need **getDerivedStateFromProps** for this. You can do simply like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class Task extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      x: 10,
      y: 10,
      width: 200,
      height: 35
    };
  }

  expand = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        height: this.state.height * 2
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.height);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        x={this.state.x}
        y={this.state.y}
        width={this.state.width}
        height={this.state.height}
      >
        <div
          className="task"
          style={{
            width: this.state.width - 22 + "px",
            height: this.state.height - 22 + "px"
          }}
          onClick={this.expand}
        >
          Hello {this.props.name}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  // static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  //   return {
  //     x: props.x,
  //     y: props.y,
  //     width: props.width,
  //     height: props.height
  //   };
  // }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Task x={10} y={10} width={200} height={35} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-noether-s1xw5?file=/src/App.js:0-1257

If you want to update state value if props value change you can use **componentDidUpdate** for this. It is better way of handling updated props and state

Comment: Thank you, I was using getDerivedStateFromProps incorrectly based on another answer. The goal for my code was to be able to have the size updated from parent components through props, as well as within the component. The componentDidUpdate method seems to work for this.

Comment: Yes read there docs they explicitly said this: 
`If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate lifecycle instead.`

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason for using getDerivedStateFromProps?
Without it, the code should work.

This is from react docs:

> `getDerivedStateFromProps` is invoked right before calling the render
> method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should
> return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.
>
> This method exists for rare use cases where the state depends on
> changes in props over time. For example, it might be handy for
> implementing a  component that compares its previous and
> next children to decide which of them to animate in and out.